# Fail to get response from php script via Android Volley

Tags: php, android, android-volley

In Android Studio, I am trying to send a `HTTP get request` to a PHP script via `Volley`. I have checked the PHP link, it's valid. But for some reason, I keep getting an error for response.Instead of getting the PHP script response. Any idea?

```
public class FourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button bn;
private TextView txt;
private String server_url = "http://192.168.0.152/server.php";

public FourActivity() {
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_four);
    bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bn);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(FourActivity.this);

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                             txt.setText(response);
                             requestQueue.stop();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    txt.setText("error");
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    requestQueue.stop();
                }
            }
            );
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


        }
    });
}
```

}

Errorlog

[image]

Comment: Please show the error logs.

Comment: it just show the word "error" in the android

Comment: Provide what your printStackTrace says not your  Textview message

Comment: may i ask where can i see it?

Comment: In logcat . Provide all the logs after response comes from the server

Comment: Have you added internet permission on the manifest ?

Comment: Small tip: Always check logs first, after that if you are unable to understand whats going on, then only post to stack overflow ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164395/discussion-between-sp4rx-and-epiphany).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission on your app **manifest** .

Hope this helps.